# save json file to specific folder with python

Tags: python, json, file, visual-studio-code, mkdir

I am saving json file from my code using `os.mkdir(path)` which creates the json folder containing json file, now I want to store only json file to the folder without creating the folder of json containing file, please help me, thanks in advance

```
cwd=os.getcwd()#current directory
os.chdir(cwd)
#print(cwd)
path=cwd+'/'+json_folder_name
if  os.path.isdir(path):
    shutil.rmtree(path)
os.mkdir(json_folder_name)
```

Comment: Where's the code where you write the json file to storage `os.mkdir` is specifically just for making a folder

Comment: Or is that what you're wondering, how to write a json file in the first place

Answer (score 2):

You can open a file handle and use [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage).

```
import json

with open("/path/to/file.json", "w+") as f:
    json.dump(object_to_write, f)
```